# Troubleshooting some mildly convoluted code, inserting 'missing $' without good reason

Tags: macros, formatting, line-breaking

I'm making a template for my university for Master's/Doctorate theses, and I'm building off of what I've learned from the Thesis template in sharelatex. I'm encountering an error, though, which prevents me from compiling. I had made some changes which caused it to stop compiling, removed the errors, but it still won't do...so, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm pasting what I feel is relevant from the .cls and the .tex documents.

The target format is [page 16 and 17 of the UML style guide PDF at the link referred to here](https://www.uml.edu/docs/thesis_guide_tcm18-3515_tcm18-65590.pdf)

In the UMLThesis.cls (below) there's an issue using \committeemembers. Commenting out the lines allows it to compile, but I still get the error with a 'missing $' somewhere, and another error saying 'there's no line to end'. An extra pair of files (blank) are required to compile, called "lstpatch.sty" and "vector.sty". I have no idea why they're required.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{UMLThesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
%\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}

\newcommand{\supervisorSig}[1]{%
    \justifying
    Signature of Thesis Supervisor: \xleaders\hbox{\underline{ }}\hfill\kern0pt \\
    \newlength{\remaining}
    \setlength{\remaining}{\textwidth-\widthof{Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad#1}}
    Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad\underline{#1\hspace{\remaining}}\par \\
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    Signatures of Other Thesis Committee Members: \\}

\newcommand{\committeeMember}[1]{%
    \justifying
    Committee Member Signature: \xleaders\hbox{\underline{ }}\hfill\kern0pt \\
    %\newlength{\remaining}
    %\setlength{\remaining}{\textwidth-\widthof{Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad#1}}
    %Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad\underline{#1\hspace{\remaining}}
    #1}

\newcommand{\prevDegree}[3]{%
    #1 \uppercase{#2} \left( #3 \right)}

\newcommand\SignaturePage[6]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \singlespacing
    \vspace*{1 in}
    \uppercase{%
        \centering
        % Title of thesis
        \large{#1} \\
        \vspace{2\baselineskip} \\
        %Author section, and previous degrees
        \normalsize{BY \vspace{2\baselineskip} \\ \MakeUppercase{\authornames} \\ #2 \vspace{3\baselineskip} \\
        submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements \\
        % degree title
        for the degree of \MakeUppercase{\degreeName} \\
        % department name
        \MakeUppercase{\deptName} \\
        \MakeUppercase{\univName}}}
\vfill
\small{%
    \newlength{\authline}
    \setlength{\authline}{3.75 in-\widthof{\small{Author: }}}
    \newlength{\autharea}
    \setlength{\autharea}{\widthof{\small{Author: }}+\authline}
    \newlength{\dateline}
    \setlength{\dateline}{5.75 in-\autharea-\widthof{\small{Date: }}}
    %\underline{#1\hspace*{\remaining}}\par
    \justifying
    Signature of \\
    Author: \underline{\hspace{\authline}}Date: \underline{\hspace{\dateline}} 
    \\ 
    #3
    \committeeMember{#4} 
    \committeeMember{#5} 
    \committeeMember{#6}}
\cleardoublepage}

\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\newcommand{\authornames}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[2]{\newcommand{\facName}{#1}\newcommand{\facTitle}    {#2}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[2]{\newcommand{\degreeNameShort}{#1}\newcommand{\degreeName}{#2}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\newcommand{\deptName}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\newcommand{\univName}{#1}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\doublespacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 1.0in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace,bm}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{array, makecell}  % <--- changed
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand*{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Below is the UMLThesis.tex, error is attributed to the 4th input option to \SignaturePage

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{UMLThesis}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

% Set up the Title Page
\title      {This is a formattable \\ thesis title, and seems to \\ work without error}
\authors    {My name} %call with \authorNames
\faculty    {My PI}{King professor guy} %call with \facName and \facTitle
\department {Department within College} %call with \depName
\degree     {M.S.}{Masters of Science} %call with \degreeNameShort and \degreeName
\university {University of Massachusetts Lowell} %call with \univName

\setstretch{1.3}  % It is better to have smaller font and larger line spacing than the other way round

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

\SignaturePage{
        % Input the name of the title, using '\\' as a manual linebreak
        Manually labeling the \\ manually spaced \\ title page
    }{
        % Input your previous degrees from least to most prestigious using the \prevdegree{abbreviation}{university}{year} function as show, and '\\' as manual line breaks between each degree
        \prevDegree{B.S.}{University of Massachusetts Lowell}{2014} 
    }{
        % Create the signatures
        \supervisorSig{\facName, Ph.D.} % Use this for a master's thesis
        %\dissertationSig{\facName, Ph.D.} % Use this for a doctorate thesis
    }{
        % First committee member
        \facName, Ph.D.
    }{
        % Second committee member
        Committee member 2, Ph.D.
    }{
        % Third committee member
        Committee member 3, Ph.D.
    }
\clearpage  % Declaration ended, now start a new page
\end{document}
```

Ancillary questions:

1. Do I need to do that whole "\def\baseclass{book}" through "\LoadClass{\baseclass}" deal?
2. How do I make this first page not listed as "i" in the front-matter? This page is like a cover, rather than an actual first page.
3. Why does changing the '\' to '\newline' inside of the \newcommand{\SignaturePage} mess up the centering? The document has a left margin of 1.5" if that matters

Comment: If I run your example I get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \setstretch`

Comment: The class shows multiple errors, notably using size changes as if they have an argument, `\small{Author: }` for example I assume that `\vspace{2\baselineskip} \\ `  generates a no line her to end error as you can't end a line in vertical mode

Comment: I was under the impression that size changes could be set with arguments, such that once the argument closes, the text returns to whatever size it was previously. Thus, if `Author: ` has a larger length than `\small{Author: }` this will be captured to make the line extend to the margin correctly?

As for the the `\vspace{2\baselineskip} \\` I was just trying to make it create more than one space. I don't understand all of the technical bits of the language, but it worked and looked accurate once I typed it out.

Comment: I'm including all of the `\usepackage{}` commands to make sure we're on the same page, just in case

Comment: I get the feeling that I should just restart this .cls from scratch, rather than frankenstein another document into it? I think I'll give that a shot tonight.

Comment: In the macro `\prevDegree` you are using `\left` and `\right`, which are allowed only in math mode. That will throw a `missing $` error. But as David said there are a lot of other issues...

Comment: You chose the worst starting point you could have found.  Start over from scratch with nothing!

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors about `lstpatch` and `vector` are due to

```
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
```

they were presumably locally available classes, but if you are not using them you should just delete those line. (In general you should delete all the packages that you are not using, which would get the class a lot closer to the base `book` class. Hopefully you don't use `lipsum` in your actual document for example.

never use `\\` at the end of a paragraph (where it produces bad output and a warning about underfull hbox) or in vertical mode (where it is an error) the class has

```
}\par \\
```

where the `\\` will always be in vertical mode because of `\par` so will give an error. Just delete the `\\` there.

size commands do not take an argument so a use such as `\small{Author: }` the braces do not do anything and the `\small` will extend to the end of the document unless (as here) there is some outer environment or group that limits the scope.

The math error about missing `$` is due to the use of `\left` which is not appropriate here, that is a math mode command, and you do not want scaled brackets here.

not strictly and error but it is bad practice to use `\newlength` inside another macro, so I moved the declarations outside. In practice her you only use the macro once so it doesn't do much harm but in general you just want to allocate a register once, not each time the macro is used.

After those changes to the class it runs without error

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{UMLThesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
%\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}

\newcommand{\supervisorSig}[1]{%
    \justifying
    Signature of Thesis Supervisor: \xleaders\hbox{\underline{ }}\hfill\mbox{}\par
    \newlength{\remaining}
    \setlength{\remaining}{\textwidth-\widthof{Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad#1}}
    Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad\underline{#1\hspace{\remaining}}\par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    Signatures of Other Thesis Committee Members: \par}

\newcommand{\committeeMember}[1]{%
    \justifying
    Committee Member Signature: \xleaders\hbox{\underline{ }}\hfill\mbox{}\par
    %\newlength{\remaining}
    %\setlength{\remaining}{\textwidth-\widthof{Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad#1}}
    %Name Typed:\quad\quad\quad\quad\underline{#1\hspace{\remaining}}
    #1}

\newcommand{\prevDegree}[3]{%
    #1 \uppercase{#2} (#3)}

    \newlength{\authline}
    \newlength{\autharea}
    \newlength{\dateline}

\newcommand\SignaturePage[6]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \singlespacing
    \vspace*{1 in}
    \uppercase{%
        \centering
        % Title of thesis
        \large{#1} \par
        \vspace{2\baselineskip} \par
        %Author section, and previous degrees
        \normalsize{BY \vspace{2\baselineskip} \par \MakeUppercase{\authornames} \par #2 \vspace{3\baselineskip} \par
        submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements \par
        % degree title
        for the degree of \MakeUppercase{\degreeName} \par
        % department name
        \MakeUppercase{\deptName} \par
        \MakeUppercase{\univName}}}
\vfill
{\small
    \setlength{\authline}{3.75 in-\widthof{\small Author: }}
    \setlength{\autharea}{\widthof{\small Author: }+\authline}
    \setlength{\dateline}{5.75 in-\autharea-\widthof{\small Date: }}
    %\underline{#1\hspace*{\remaining}}\par
    \justifying
    Signature of \par
    Author: \underline{\hspace{\authline}}Date: \underline{\hspace{\dateline}} 
    \par 
    #3
    \committeeMember{#4} 
    \committeeMember{#5} 
    \committeeMember{#6}
  \par}
\cleardoublepage}

\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\newcommand{\authornames}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[2]{\newcommand{\facName}{#1}\newcommand{\facTitle}    {#2}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[2]{\newcommand{\degreeNameShort}{#1}\newcommand{\degreeName}{#2}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\newcommand{\deptName}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\newcommand{\univName}{#1}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\doublespacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 1.0in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace,bm}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments


\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{array, makecell}  % <--- changed
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand*{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Comment: In the segment of `\uppercase{}`, is there a way to prevent the `\par` from resetting `\singlespacing`?

Comment: `\par` doesn't have any effect on double or single spacing, so I do not understand the comment, sorry.

Comment: So, I'm implementing your changes one by one. I've updated `\supervisorSig`, I've uncommented the latter lines of my version of `\committeeMember` without updating to your version of it, and now visually it closely matches the official PDF version of the sample template. However, when I switched `\\` to `\par` in `\SignaturePage`, the lines of the title are no longer single spaced

Comment: @Ronen possibly set `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` in that local group?

Comment: I managed to do it using the `\begin{singlespacing}...\end{singlespacing` method. I inserted it into every `\newcommand` so that I don't have to mess with `\parskip` lengths anywhere. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Ronen that sounds wrong (or at least if doing that makes any difference presumably the extra space was unrelated to using `\par` and it was doublespaced before with `\\ `